# Programmatically obtain RF test result xml file name and path

Tags: java, robotframework

I am asked to work on a RF Java Test Library that can post test results to a different service through SOAP. While the concept seems easy to understand, I am stuck on using RF due to inexperience.

Ideally, I will write the Test Library ABC which contains a method that takes a string as input parameter. The string would be the location of the test result xml file. Then I add ABC to a RF Test Case. When the Test Case is run, ABC will get called. The code inside ABC would parse this file to get the list of test case id and results then send this data to the external service using SOAP.

The difficulty now is how to make RF know the value of the test rest file and pass the value to ABC during run time. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an external system during test execution, the best way is to use the [listener interface](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.3#using-listener-interface) instead of a test library, which is similar to how TestNG and JUnit solve this problem.

Your listener will have access to the same information that is being written to the results XML file including metadata and tags, where you are presumably going to store test case IDs.

EDIT:
You can ignore the data sent to the listener and still work with the XML file. If you have a output_file method in your listener, Robot Framework will send the path to the output XML file once it has done writing to it. Then you can open it an process it.

You can also externalize the whole process and create an application or script that takes the location of the output XML file(s) as parameter(s).